# Post data from DOM to express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to connect a signup form to my express server to register new users.  I'm having trouble sending a post request properly from DOM.

I have the express server running and if I try to create a user through Postman it sends a welcome email and saves the user to my MongoDB as expected but I am having trouble sending the data from the signup form correctly.

Here is a copy of my express route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();
const User = require('../models/user');

const sendWelcomeEmail = require('../emails/account');

// Route for creating a new user
router.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
    const user = new User(req.body);

    try {
        await user.save();
        sendWelcomeEmail(user.email, user.name);

        res.status(201).send({ user });
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

And here is my function where I am trying to make the post request with the form data.

```
$(function() {
    $('#register').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const name = document.querySelector('#InputName').value;
        const email = document.querySelector('#InputEmail').value;
        const phone = document.querySelector('#InputPhone').value;
        console.log(name, email, phone);

        if (!name || !email || !phone) {
            $('#msgDiv')
                .show()
                .html('All fields are required.');

            $.ajax({
                url: '/users',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    email: email,
                    phone: phone
                }
            }).done(function(data) {
                if (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#msgDiv')
                        .removeClass('alert-danger')
                        .addClass('alert-success')
                        .html(data.message)
                        .show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I was expecting to at least get a new user in my database with this but I am not seeing anything. I'm sure I'm missing something basic and I apologize if this has been answered somewhere else already, I'm just having trouble applying any of the answers I'm finding to my problem.

Comment: What's the status code returned from the server?. Does it reach the route? Put a `console.log` in there. Also, make sure you have `body-parser` to access the posted values.

Comment: Need to use a body parser for sure. Note that `$.ajax` default content type is form encoded, not json

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that out.

Comment: `if (!name || !email || !phone)` this line is going to evaluate to false if all elements contains some value and you're firing `ajax` call inside it